# Dismiss facebook window programmatically

Tags: ios, facebook

My requirement is to close Facebook window in certain conditions via code.
I am using **Facebook iOS SDK 3.5.1.**

Is there any way to get visible (Facebook) screen on running app or to dismiss Facebook screen programmatically?

I am using facebook for 2 scenarios-

1. for login
2. for sending app request.

**Code for both are below-**

**1. For login:**

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
if (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated || !appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
    // Create a new, logged out session.
    NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"user_birthday",@"user_photos", @"email", @"user_location", @"user_hometown", nil];
    appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
}

[appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                 FBSessionState status,
                                                 NSError *error) {
    if (appDelegate.session.state!=258 && appDelegate.session.state!=257) {
        [self accessTokenFound:appDelegate.session.accessToken];
    }
}];
```

**2. For app requests**

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
[params setObject:friendID forKey:@"to"];

// Display the requests dialog
[FBWebDialogs
 presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:appDelegate.session
 message:message
 title:nil
 parameters:params
 handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
     if (error) {
         NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
     } else {
         if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
             NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
         } else {
             NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];
             if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"request"]) {
                 NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
             } else {
                 NSString *requestID = [urlParams valueForKey:@"request"];
                 [self requestSentSuccessfully];
             }
         }
     }
 }];
```

Comment: Could you show your code, how you are showing the facebook in your viewController?

Comment: Please see code in edited question.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to close the dialogs?

Comment: Hi,
Did you get solution to your problem? I am also facing the same issue in my application.